# openssl_encrypt is invalid in PHP5.6 & Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrading php

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am using the openssl_encrypt/openssl_decrypt library on my project server(Ubuntu 16.04 + PHP5.6). The script had been working fine until last week I installed the php-Imap library on the server, The script is unable to encrypt/decrypt the code using OpenSSL now.

I wrote the simplest testing code as below to test the PHP-OpenSSL library:

```
<?php
    $algorithm = 'AES-128-CBC';
    $arr = 'this is a test...';
    $iv = '1234123412341234';
    $key = 'aslfkkasdsalklkdasflwefwewfloiuy';
    $encrypt = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($arr), $algorithm, substr($key, 0, 16), 0,$iv);
    $decrypt = json_decode(openssl_decrypt($encrypt, $algorithm, substr($key, 0, 16), 0,$iv));
    var_dump($encrypt,  openssl_error_string(), $decrypt );
    exit;
```

It executes successfully on my machine, but unable to execute on the server, the execution result on the server is:

```
$ php test.php
bool(false)
bool(false)
NULL
```

The PHP information on the Ubuntu server is:

[image]
[image]

**Does anyone have any suggestions?**